# Combination of the characteristics of the images

Tags: image, matlab, combinations, glcm

I use three image features (Colour Histogram, GLCM, and Hu's seven invariant moments) in my project QBIC system using MATLAB.

I don't know how to make the combination between such features.

Comment: Combining all of those is like trying to combine an apple, orange and pineapple together so you can build a car.  They all measure completely different things and putting them together to facilitate a retrieval system will be disastrous.  Focus on ONE kind of feature, then make other features that are based on the single feature and combine them together.

Comment: I worked each feature alone but to complete my project I need to make a combination between them to find the exactly results.